# Windows forms listbox.selecteditem displaying "System.Data.DataRowView" instead of actual value

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am creating a Windows form application in Visual Studio 2010. I have an Access database which has a table 'ResearcherInfo'.

In my windows form, I have a listbox which gets populated with the contents of the column name 'Researcher Name' of this table.

However when I try to get the selected items of this text box, it only returns me a null value or sometimes System.Data.DataRowView depending on how I access it

I have tried

```
    string name = projectmembers_lst.SelectedItem.ToString();
```

While debugging when I hover the mouse over the 'projectmembers_lst' word, it  correctly shows me projectmembers_lst = {SelectedItem = "Jerome"}

but on hovering over the string 'name', it shows "name = "System.Data.DataRowView""

i even tried copying to an array

```
    foreach (Object selecteditem in projectmembers_lst.SelectedItems)
    {

        object[] objCollection = new object[projectmembers_lst.SelectedItems.Count];

        projectmembers_lst.SelectedItems.CopyTo(objCollection, 0);

        MessageBox.Show(objCollection[0] as string);
    }
```

Nothing gets me the selected items. I am not sure what is wrong here.

**Populating the List Box:**

1) I have the added the access table 'ResearcherInfo'. as a data source for the web form application.

2) In the properties of the Listbox, under the Datasource tab, I have linked this table and given the display member and value member property of the Listbox as the column name 'Researcher Name' of the table.

So basically my Listbox displays the Researcher Names from the Researcher info table. attached is a snap shot. [image]

Comment: May be you need .SelectedValue? Could you show us how are you filling list box?

Comment: I have edited my initial question in response.

Comment: thank you. It worked with the answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

without seeing how you're populating it, it's tough to guess.

try ((objCollection[0] as DataViewRow)[0] as string

Comment: Brilliant. This worked ((objCollection[0] as DataRowView)[1] as string). Thank you very much.